# Fraunhofer Diffraction and amplitude

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, diffraction, huygens-principle

[This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph5B/oneslit09.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi0q9SIycDlAhWG8HMBHSPpBrMQFjAGegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw180-jdQ56OjH-8d-GJuIKb) set of lecture notes shows single slit diffraction in which the slit is divided into a large number of point sources(let's say $N$), each emmiting a wave of amplitude $\Delta E$.

They showed that if every wave interferes constructively at the central point on the screen (corresponding to $0^{\circ}$ angle) then the resultant amplitude would be

$$E = N*\Delta E$$

But since each source is considered to be a point source (as per the Huygens Principle) the amplitude of every wavelet should also decrease with distance traveled by wave, which they haven't considered.

How can these facts be resolved?

Comment: It's an approximation for the case in which the slit width is small relative to the distance to the screen.

Comment: I think you have uncovered a problem or error